# Creating a keyboard that sends specific linked images?

Tags: java, android, image, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I have been tasked with creating a way for somebody to send very specific, encoded images at the touch of a button. My original way around this was just to create a custom SMS Application that had a few buttons under the text area, but then I came across the problem of MMS messages being a huge pain in the rear to encode and decode.

Having realized I might possibly be able to do something like this has sparked my interest.

I am specifically wanting to create a 'table' of sorts that's linked to the keyboard so you can switch back and forth between the default text and image inputs (either by a button or something else entirely, I don't care).

Basically, I'd be adding a button that functions just about exactly like the 'emoji' button, however instead of sending a Unicode character that corresponds to an image, I want to send that image as if I'd selected it directly from the gallery. I believe I could do this with a simple listview, but haven't the slightest idea behind the code that selecting the image would have to execute to send it.

Would it be possible to do this, or am I just chasing a dream?

NOTE: I am not expecting a fully-coded answer, just something I may be able to run off of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the best way to figure out what you are doing is to find a basic open source base and build (or remove) from. It's still fairly rewarding, as you know that you've still built something.